# Amplify Reset Password Hangs

Tags: aws-amplify

I used amplify's `withAuthenticator` as shown below for my `/mainPage` path.  But when I tried to reset password, supply the confirmation code and submit it, the page hangs. It should refresh my `/mainPage` page.

```
import { withAuthenticator } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";
import "@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css";
function MainPage({ signOut, user }) {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello {user.username}</h1>
      <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
    </>
  );
}
export default withAuthenticator(MainPage);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Lots of missing information here but.. here's go nothing

1. **page hangs == there was an error** which can be viewed and inspected by your browser's `developer tools` - you should attach the error here in order to help others to assist (next time of course)
2. do you use the default `reset password flow` or make something custom?
3. in any case - why do you use the `signOut` method for this process? the user is not signed in (forgot password) so there is no point to sign out

The only scenerio I can think of is if the user is forced to change password (e.g. - getting kicked off with the `signOut` method, change password and sign in again). Even for that use-case - the `signOut` method alone (as present in your code) is only the first phase of this process (and not the entire process)

With that being said, I'll try to suggest a process that will simplify things for you (as the name `Amplify` applies) - reset one's password by using the build-in mechanism already provided with the library (please read the [docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/manageusers/q/platform/js/#forgot-password))

Long story short, the process would be:

- User need to change password (forgot or forced to perform this action)
- An email with temporary code is then send to user's email (this code is only valid for one hour - please generate it only when user is able to actually change current password)
- User copy the code from email to your form, and then enter the new password
- After confirmation - password changed. It's up to you to decide if you want to enter user into your app of force re-entry (e.g. typing the new password in the login screen in order to sign-in)

And you can use the `forgotPassword` and `forgotPasswordSubmit` methods in order to fulfill that process (more information in the link provided above) . In any other case (you have a custom flow) - please share more details

One last technical note:

In `react` this form of event handling

```
<button onClick={asyncFunc} >I am a button!</button>
```

Is the short way of wrtiting

```
<button onClick={async () => { await asyncFunc1(); await asyncFunc2() } }>
    I am a button!
</button>
```

So either write your own custom `async function` and use the short way (preferred) or use the long way and use several functions in order to materialize your async process steps

Good luck

Comment: There'e no error.  Not yet signed in.  I just click forget password, got the email and submit the new password.  It just hangs there saying "submitting..." without error in the console.

Comment: interesting... can you please share your full code so I can better inspect? Also - does the `resset password request` is status is `pending` or has it completed with errors? (can be observed via the `network` tab under your browser's `developer tools`)